# User Management Token - React Native / MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, firebase, react-native, authentication

I am new to react-native development. I need to implement User Authentication for Login and Sign Up for my react native apps. I saw some tutorial using Firebase Authentication but I plan to use the mongoDB instead of Firebase. I am not sure how to use mongoDB. For firebase its pretty simple because they provide API URLS and all we need to do is just send the request with our data. But when I am trying to use mongoDB I am not sure how to implement and get the token key back from server side. Do I need to write server side code for mongoDb or they have simplified API URL like firebase? Please Help . Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a lot of concepts.

Firebase is a BaaS (Backend as a Service), so it sell you a backend already done with authentication, database ecc.

Mongo DB is a database, it could be IaaS (Infrastructure as a Service) or Paas (Platform as a Service), but it's not a BaaS.

So you can't just replace firebase with mongo, but you need to build your whole backend and have a server to deploy it. You need to manage environments, authentication, security and many other feature that firebase already offers you.

Comment: Understand. Will explore more that part. Thank You for your guidance.